# horizontally center 45deg rotated div

Tags: html, css

Im trying to create this shape using css and center it horizontally: http://oi64.tinypic.com/etctn8.jpg

so far i've got this:

```css
#circlewrap { transform: rotate(45deg); margin-top: 150px; }

#circleone, #circletwo { 
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block; 
  height: 300px; 
  width: 150px; 
  background: #079491;
}

#circleone { border-radius: 300px 0 0 300px; }
#circletwo { border-radius: 0 300px 300px 0; margin-left: -1px; top: 15px; }

#circleone:after, #circletwo:before {
  content: "";  
  position: absolute; 
  width: 1px; 
  background: #079491;
}

#circleone:after { height: 500px; right: 2px; bottom: -100px; }
#circletwo:before { width: 1px; height: 380px; left: 25px; bottom: -20px; }
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="circlewrap">
      <div id="circleone"></div>
      <div id="circletwo"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now how do i center everything horizontally? 
setting `margin-right: auto;` and `margin-left: auto` didn't gave me the result i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `width` and `height` to `#circlewrap`

```css
#circlewrap {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  margin-top: 150px;
  background-color: red;
  height: 350px;
  width: 350px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
#circleone,
#circletwo {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 300px;
  width: 150px;
  background: #079491;
}
#circleone {
  border-radius: 300px 0 0 300px;
}
#circletwo {
  border-radius: 0 300px 300px 0;
  margin-left: -1px;
  top: 15px;
}
#circleone:after,
#circletwo:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  background: #079491;
}
#circleone:after {
  height: 500px;
  right: 2px;
  bottom: -100px;
}
#circletwo:before {
  width: 1px;
  height: 380px;
  left: 25px;
  bottom: -20px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="circlewrap">
    <div id="circleone"></div>
    <div id="circletwo"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: if i want to add a heading and center it both horizontally and vertically, what is the best way to do so?  since the div is rotated - setting `position:absolute;`  
`top: 50%;`  
`left: 50%;`  
`transform: translate(-50%, -50%);`  to the heading doesn't center it (the heading "escapes" the middle)

Answer (score 0):

You can set text-align:center; to your body to center everything. Additionally add display: -webkit-inline-box; to your #circlewrap.

**CSS:**

```
body {text-align:center;}
#circlewrap { transform: rotate(45deg); display: -webkit-inline-box; }

#circleone, #circletwo { 
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block; 
  height: 300px; 
  width: 150px; 
  background: #079491;
}

#circleone { border-radius: 300px 0 0 300px; }
#circletwo { border-radius: 0 300px 300px 0; margin-left: -1px; top: 15px; }

#circleone:after, #circletwo:before {
  content: "";  
  position: absolute; 
  width: 1px; 
  background: #079491;
}

#circleone:after { 
  height: 500px; 
  right: 2px; 
  bottom: -100px; 
}

#circletwo:before { 
  width: 1px; 
  height: 380px; 
  left: 25px; 
  bottom: -20px; 
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="circlewrap">
  <div id="circleone"></div>
  <div id="circletwo"></div>
</div>
```

Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rv1qr7w1/3/